# ebpf unknown opcode comparing strings

Tags: ebpf, bpf, bcc-bpf

I currently try to filter calls to a function by command. I try to do so with the following code where ##REPLACE_comm## is replaced by python by the command name. The double backslash are cause I am using bcc. The following code throws an error when loading:

```c
if(1){
    char filter[TASK_COMM_LEN] = "##REPLACE_comm##";
    char command[TASK_COMM_LEN];
    bpf_get_current_comm(&command, sizeof(command));
    for(u16 i = 0; i<=TASK_COMM_LEN; i++){
        if(command[i] == '\\0' && filter[i] == '\\0'){
            break;    
        }
        if(command[i] == filter[i]){
            continue;    
        }
        return 0;
    }
}
```

The error is:

```
unknown opcode 70

HINT: The 'unknown opcode' can happen if you reference a global or static variable, or data in read-only section. For example, 'char *p = "hello"' will result in p referencing a read-only section, and 'char p[] = "hello"' will have "hello" stored on the stack.
```

I feel like I already made sure the variables are on the stack by allocating space and not just having a pointer but it doesnt work. What am I missing?